# Selected option not persisting - React

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Have a simple drop down list being populated from an axios request. It is working outside of the fact that the actual selected item in the "Select a team" drop down does not persist when selected and the default value "Select a team" continues to show. What am I missing here, any help is greatly appreciated!

```html
import KeeperTable from "./components/KeeperTable";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import "./App.css";

const App = () => {
  const [selectedYear, setSelectedYear] = useState("");
  const [selectedTeam, setSelectedTeam] = useState("");
  const [managerList, setManagerList] = useState([]);

  const handleChange = () => {
    setSelectedYear(document.getElementById("ft-year-select").value);
    setSelectedTeam(document.getElementById("ft-team-select").value);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    async function populateManagers() {
      axios.get("/getManagers").then((res) => {
        setManagerList(res.data);
      });
    }
    populateManagers();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="ddl-container">
        <div className="ddlStyle">
          <select onChange={handleChange} id="ft-year-select">
            <option default value="#">
              Select a Year
            </option>
            <option value="2020">2020</option>
            <option value="2021">2021</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div className="ddlStyle">
          <select onChange={handleChange} id="ft-team-select">
            <option default value="#">
              Select a Team
            </option>
            {managerList.map((e) => {
              return [
                <option key={uuidv4()} value={e.manager}>
                  {e.manager}
                </option>,
              ];
            })}
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <KeeperTable yearSearch={selectedYear} teamSearch={selectedTeam} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Adding a screenshot for referance. Here you can see that the manager "Dan" is selected yet his name doesn't appear in the input.

[image: Image showing an example]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not explicitly mark as selected any `option`, and since you do `key={uuidv4()}` for each one, it means than on each re-render the options are considered different that then previous render, and so do not keep their default highlight.

You can provide a `value` prop to the `select` element and that will take care of highlighting the correct option.

```
<select onChange={handleChange} id="ft-team-select" value={selectedTeam} >
```

---

Initial answer (below) is wrong for react.

<strike>You will need to mark the selected one with</strike>

```
     {managerList.map((e) => {
          return [
            <option key={uuidv4()} value={e.manager} selected={e.manager === selectedTeam}>
              {e.manager}
            </option>,
          ];
        })}
```

Comment: Is there any way to take care of the console warning I receive when using this?

"Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>..."

Comment: @cd131313 yes, just updated my answer. The initial answer was wrong. Just use `value` and you should be ok.